# dashboardHeader allowed elements (tabs) in shinyDashboard

Tags: shinydashboard

Any idea how i can add tabs in the dashboardHeader so i can achieve this look found in the shinyapps gallery:

https://gallery.shinyapps.io/TSupplyDemand/

[image: top menu example]

Comment: I don't think that example is using `shinydashboard`? Looks more like a `shiny::navbarPage`.